# How to get the desired pid from the log file

Tags: perl

I am trying to automate one task for my project there i have to parse one log file and search for specific pid. If that pid encounter more then 50 time then i  have to print my message.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; 

open(my $fh,"<","UIlogs.txt") or die "can not open the file $!";
my @lines = <$fh>;
close($fh);
 my $count=0;
for(my $i=0; $i<=$#lines;$i++)
{

  if($lines[$i] =~ m/Input event injection from pid (\d+) failed/gi)
  {
    #print"UI freez\n";
   print"$1\n"; 

  } 

}
```

Log:

```
07-10 16:36:43.632   784   784 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2019 failed.

07-10 16:36:43.632   784   795 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2019 failed.

07-10 16:36:45.114  2041  2041 D AndroidRuntime: 

07-10 16:36:45.114  2041  2041 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<

07-10 16:36:45.114  2041  2041 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF

07-10 16:36:45.124  2041  2041 D dalvikvm: Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0

07-10 16:36:45.124  2041  2041 D dalvikvm: Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0

07-10 16:36:45.134  2041  2041 D dalvikvm: Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0

07-10 16:36:45.134  2041  2041 D dalvikvm: Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0

07-10 16:36:45.244  2041  2041 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.input.Input

07-10 16:36:45.244  2041  2041 I Input   : injectKeyEvent: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=166218, downTime=166218, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }

07-10 16:36:45.254   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:45.254  2041  2041 I Input   : injectKeyEvent: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=166218, downTime=166218, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }

07-10 16:36:45.254   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:45.254  2041  2041 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

07-10 16:36:45.254  2041  2050 D dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 94K, 17% free 479K/576K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 3ms

07-10 16:36:45.254   784  1016 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2041 failed.

07-10 16:36:45.254   784  1083 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2041 failed.

07-10 16:36:52.932  2061  2061 D AndroidRuntime: 

07-10 16:36:52.932  2061  2061 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<

07-10 16:36:52.932  2061  2061 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF

07-10 16:36:52.942  2061  2061 D dalvikvm: Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0

07-10 16:36:52.942  2061  2061 D dalvikvm: Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0

07-10 16:36:52.952  2061  2061 D dalvikvm: Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0

07-10 16:36:52.952  2061  2061 D dalvikvm: Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0

07-10 16:36:53.082  2061  2061 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.monkey.Monkey

07-10 16:36:53.092  2061  2061 D dalvikvm: Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 163 unimplemented (abstract) methods

07-10 16:36:53.112   784  1076 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity} from pid 2061

07-10 16:36:53.122   784  1076 I ActivityManager: Start proc com.android.contacts for activity com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity: pid=2077 uid=10000 gids={50000, 3003, 1015, 1028}

07-10 16:36:53.212  2077  2077 I ContactsIntentResolver: Called with action: android.intent.action.MAIN

07-10 16:36:53.232  2077  2092 I AccountTypeManager: Loaded meta-data for 1 account types, 0 accounts in 19ms(wall) 5ms(cpu)

07-10 16:36:53.272  2077  2077 I ContactPhotoManager: Cache adj: 1.0

07-10 16:36:53.463  2077  2077 D libEGL  : loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so

07-10 16:36:53.463  2077  2077 D libEGL  : loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so

07-10 16:36:53.463  2077  2077 D libEGL  : loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so

07-10 16:36:53.473  2077  2077 I Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.6.04.02.02.109.046_msm8960_JB_2.6_CL3925444_release_AU (CL3925444)

07-10 16:36:53.473  2077  2077 I Adreno-EGL: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.08

07-10 16:36:53.473  2077  2077 I Adreno-EGL: Build Date: 07/09/13 Tue

07-10 16:36:53.473  2077  2077 I Adreno-EGL: Local Branch: mybranch1230998

07-10 16:36:53.473  2077  2077 I Adreno-EGL: Remote Branch: quic/jb_3.1

07-10 16:36:53.473  2077  2077 I Adreno-EGL: Local Patches: NONE

07-10 16:36:53.473  2077  2077 I Adreno-EGL: Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.6.04.02.02.109.046 + e363aa2 + 76767df +  NOTHING

07-10 16:36:53.523  2077  2077 D OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0

07-10 16:36:53.623   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:53.623   784   857 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity: +511ms

07-10 16:36:53.623   784  1016 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:53.633   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:53.633   784  1103 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:54.133   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:54.133   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:54.133   784  1083 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:54.133   784  1016 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:54.634   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:54.634   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:54.634   784   796 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:54.634   784   795 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:55.144   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:55.144   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:55.144   784  1103 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:55.144   784  1191 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:55.645   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:55.645   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:55.645   784  1016 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:55.655   784  1083 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:56.156   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:56.156   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:56.156   784   784 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:56.156   784   795 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:56.666   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:56.666   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:56.666   784   796 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:56.666   784  1076 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:57.167   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:57.167   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:57.167   784  1190 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:57.167   784  1191 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:57.677   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:57.677   784  1103 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:57.677   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:57.677   784  1083 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:58.188   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:58.188   784  1016 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:58.188   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:58.188   784   795 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:58.698   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:58.698   784   784 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:58.698   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:58.698   784   796 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:59.039   784   910 W QCNEJ   : |CORE| UNKOWN Unsolicited Event 6

07-10 16:36:59.209   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:59.209   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:59.209   784  1190 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:59.209   784  1103 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:59.719   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:59.719   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:36:59.719   784  1083 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:36:59.719   784   795 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:37:00.230   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:37:00.230   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:37:00.230   784  1191 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:37:00.230   784  1076 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:37:00.740   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:37:00.740   784  1103 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:37:00.740   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:37:00.740   784  1190 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:37:01.251   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:37:01.251   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:37:01.251   784  1016 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:37:01.251   784   784 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:37:01.762   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:37:01.762   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:37:01.762   784   796 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:37:01.762   784  1076 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:37:02.272   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:37:02.272   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:37:02.272   784  1191 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:37:02.272   784  1103 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:37:02.773   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:37:02.773   784   886 I InputDispatcher: Dropped event because input dispatch is disabled.

07-10 16:37:02.773   784  1190 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.

07-10 16:37:02.783   784   795 W InputManager: Input event injection from pid 2061 failed.
```

With my code i am not able to handle other pid i.e how to count only that pid which is there in the log for more then 50 time . Only one pid would be cross this count if UI freez will happen.

Comment: Do you really have a double spaced log file? Empty lines every other line?

Comment: @ TLP  ya,Empty lines every other line will be there

Comment: Ok, that does not matter for my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hash is useful for keeping track of how many *xxxxx* appears.

e.g.

```
if($lines[$i] =~ m/Input event injection from pid (\d+) failed/gi)
{
    my $foundpid = $1;
    print "Found pid:$1\n"; 
    $pids{$foundpid} += 1;
    if ( $pids{$foundpid} > 100 ) {
        print "PID $foundpid is extra naughty today!\n";
    }
}
```

Usually you only want to print one warning message for each PID that exceeds your limit, however, so we would save the processing of the hash to the end, e.g.:

```
my %pids = (); # initialise hash

for ( ... )  { # process lines
    if ( ... ) { # match line
        $pids{$foundpid} += 1;
    }
}

# now scan our hash of pids and filter those that failed the condition
foreach my $pid ( sort { $a <=> $b keys %pids ) ) {
    if ( $pids{$pid} > 100 ) {
        print( "Bad PID $pid was seen " . $pids{$pid} . " times!\n" );
    }
}
```

Later if you want to make your code a little more terse you could re-write that last part as:

```
my @failedpids = grep { $pids{$_} > 100 } keys %pids;
print( "Failed PIDs were: " );
print( join( ", ", sort { $a <=> $b } @failedpids ) );
print( "\n" );
```

Comment: `my %pids = ();` is redundant, all newly declared hashes (and arrays) are empty. `... += 1` aka `++`.

Comment: That is a perfectly valid explanation, which is why my comment is still important. You might do all sorts of things to make yourself feel at home in Perl, but you should know that it is redundant. You are by doing this teaching someone something that is incorrect, which is not ok.

Comment: I think you are taking this far too personally. Every language has its own rules about initialization, it is not like you can just decide that "because you can, you should". And in the case of telling a newbie how to do something, telling him how to do it in Perl is the correct way. Any other way would need to come with an explanation, such as `I like to assign an empty list to all my hashes and arrays just to be sure, but it is not strictly required`, or it is incorrect. It is not an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a simple counting exercise. You capture a string with a regex, and you count its frequency with a hash:

```
perl -nlwe '$a{$1}++ if /Input event injection from pid (\d+)/ 
           END { for (keys %a) { print qq($_ -> $a{$_}) } }' inject.log
```

I get this output from your input:

```
2061 -> 38
2019 -> 2
2041 -> 2
```

As a program file, it would look like this:

```
while (<>) {
    $a{$1}++ if /Input event injection from pid (\d+)/;
}
for my $key (keys %a) {
    print "$key -> $a{$key}\n";
}
```

`<>` the diamond operator either reads STDIN, or treats the arguments as file names to be used for input. `$a{$1}++` uses the string captured from the regex in a hash, and `++` increments its value.

Of course I chose a simple print for all elements, but you could simply add a check for values over 50:

```
next if $a{$key} < 50;
```

Some notes on your code:

- Don't use C-style for loops unless you really need to know the index of the array you are looping over. Instead use the Perl style, often referred to as "foreach": `for my $line (@lines)`
- Don't read the whole file into an array if you don't have to. You can simply iterate over the file handle like so: `while (<$fh>)` -- this will read one line per iteration into `$_` (or the variable of your choice, e.g. `while (my $foo = <$fh>)`), until end of file `eof`.
- It is really good to see that you are using `use strict` and warnings. Usually, `use warnings` is preferred to using `-w` on the shebang, since it is more readable, and also it is a lexical pragma, rather than global.